# jquery, selector for class within id

Tags: jquery

Below, how should I select the elements that contain the class `my_class` within the element with `id = "my_id"`?

Note that the element may also have another class, which I am not selecting for.

```
<div id = "my_id">
    <span class = "my_class hidden">hi</span>
    <span class = "my_class">hello</span>
</div>
```

was trying

```
$("#my_id [class*=my_class ]")
```

Answer (score 175, accepted):

You can use the [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) along with [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)

```
$("#my_id .my_class")
```

Comment: Can I combine this with :first (to get the first element of that class inside #my_id)?

Comment: @jakob.j `$("#my_id .my_class:first")`

Comment: Can I use the same for the class than id like $(".my_class #my_id") when id is defined inside class

Comment: This didn't work for me because of the space character. It needed to be $("#my_id.my_class")      [i.e. no space separator]

Comment: @robbpriestley That means your element has both the id of #my_id and the class of .my_class. The space is getting elements that are descendants of the #my_id element.

Answer (score 53):

Just use the plain ol' class selector.

```
$('#my_id .my_class')
```

It doesn't matter if the element also has other classes. It has the **.my_class** class, and it's somewhere inside **#my_id**, so it will match that selector.

### Regarding performance

According to the [jQuery selector performance documentation](http://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/), it's faster to use the two selectors separately, like this:

```
$('#my_id').find('.my_class')
```

Here's the relevant part of the documentation:

> ### ID-Based Selectors
>
> ```
> // Fast:
> $( "#container div.robotarm" );
>
> // Super-fast:
> $( "#container" ).find( "div.robotarm" );
> ```
>
> The `.find()` approach is faster because the first selection is handled without going through the Sizzle selector engine – ID-only selections are handled using `document.getElementById()`, which is extremely fast because it is native to the browser.

Selecting [by ID](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) or [by class](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) alone (among other things) invokes browser-supplied functions like `document.getElementById()` which are quite rapid, whereas using a [descendent selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) invokes the Sizzle engine as mentioned which, although fast, is slower than the suggested alternative.

Answer (score 13):

Always use

```
//Super Fast
$('#my_id').find('.my_class');
```

instead of

```
// Fast:
$('#my_id .my_class');
```

Have look at [JQuery Performance Rules](http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/).

Also at [Jquery Doc](http://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/)

Answer (score 3):

Also `$( "#container" ).find( "div.robotarm" );`
is equal to: `$( "div.robotarm", "#container" )`

Answer (score 1):

I think your asking to select only `<span class = "my_class">hello</span>` this element,  You have do like this, If I am understand your question correctly this is the answer,

```
$("#my_id [class='my_class']").addClass('test');
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Fe5sf/)</kbd>

Comment: `$("#my_id .my_class")` is the shorter equivalent; you don't gain anything from using the attribute selector in this case.

Comment: I hope that also did the same job as your answer, while I am answering the question you answered, I haven't noticed that since I did the answer I haven't deleted the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use find() :

```
$('#my_id').find('.my_class');
```

Or maybe:

```
$('#my_id').find('span');
```

Both methods will work for what you want