# How to select elements using jQuery by partial ID and a class at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

When I want to select all the components by a partial ID **or** by its class, I use the following.

```
var identify = $("[id*=donkey]");
var classify = $(".wonkey");
```

The thing is now that I want to restrict the set returned by **identification** so that each element still in there also is a member of **classification**.

The closest I've got by goolearching is along the [suggestion here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17417622/1525840) but that's only valid for elements that are children **under** their parent. That's not my case. I want to select the elements like this.

```
<bopp id="head-donkey" class="wonkey" />
<bopp id="donkey-butt" class="wonkey" />
<bopp id="head-donkey-butt" class="wonkey" />
```

But I want to exclude elements like this.

```
<bopp id="banana" class="wonkey" />
<bopp id="don-key" class="wonkey" />
<bopp id="donkey" class="not-won-key" />
```

I can't find any info on that operation, though...

Comment: `$("[id*=donkey].wonkey")`

Comment: @Pointy Oh my god! I'm so stupid... Can you imagine how I feel after over 30 minutes of doing those donkeys...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the solution linked by you. However, that user has a space between the selectors, which means that you're targeting the descendant using the second selector.

In your specific case, you need to omit space like this.

```
var idenclassify = $("[id*=donkey].wonkey");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple selectors to get the exact elements you need. For your example do:

`$(".wonkey[id*=donkey]")`